# Tiled CCSprite draw Assert error

Tags: iphone, cocos2d-iphone, collision-detection, draw, ccsprite

I am trying to make a collision test between 2 sprites. One of them is retrieved from a tile map array using the code

```
CCSprite *tiledsprite = [colLayer tileAt:ccp(pos1X,pos1Y)];
```

And that's the problem since trying to make the collision test inside a CCRenderTexture offscreen, everytime I call

```
[tiledsprite visit];
```

I get the the following assertion error

```
NSAssert(!usesBatchNode_, @"If CCSprite is being rendered by CCSpriteBatchNode, CCSprite#draw SHOULD NOT be called");
```

This works as it expected for the mentioned reasons, but I still need to render this tiledsprite inside the CCRenderTexture offscreen.

Is there anyway to overcome this problem and render it as normal sprite ?

I thought to extract the appropriate texture of the mentioned sprite and then draw it with a custom draw. How can I extract a specific texture from the texture atlas ?

Regards,